# nFinding Xcrossing point using Data Points

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, linear-algebra

I was going through Algorithm which identify crossing point using data points on x axis. I can understand calculation but could not understand purpose of this calculation. As per my understanding, it determine each time new y point and slope and subtract them. 
I want to insert Image also but I do not have 10 reputation point. 
Please let me know if I need to provide info.

[image: http://tinypic.com/r/izbz2e/8]

```
//This function determine the crossing point when the graph is intersecting x axis.

 XPoint findXingPoint(Curve & curve, double rfix, double vcc, int type, int pull_up)
{
    //curve class contain x and y data point
    // rfix is fixed value which is generally 50
    // vcc also fix value
    // type contain 0 and 1  
    //pull up to identify graph

    XPoint p = { 0.0, 0.0 };
    double r_fix = rfix;
    double m = -1 / r_fix;
    double c = vcc / r_fix;
    if(type)
        c=0;
    double r, s, X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4;
    r = (m * curve[0].first) + c;
    // r is a kind of y value which determine from x and y point
    s = abs(r);
    for (Curve::iterator i = curve.begin(); i != curve.end(); i++) {
    curve_point p = (*i);
    double xcurve = p.first;
    double ycurve = p.second;
    double yloadline = m * xcurve + c;
    double B = ycurve - yloadline;
    if (B >= 0 && r >= B) {
        r = B;
        X1 = xcurve;
        Y1 = yloadline;
        Y2 = ycurve;
    }
    if (B <= 0 && r >= abs(B)) {
        s = abs(B);
        X2 = xcurve;
        Y4 = yloadline;
        Y3 = ycurve;
    }
    }
    #could not understand purpose of B calculation 
    if (s == 0)
    X1 = X2;
    if (r == 0)
    X2 = X1;
    if (X1 != X2) {
    double m1, m2, c1, c2;
    m1 = (Y3 - Y2) / (X2 - X1);
    m2 = (Y4 - Y1) / (X2 - X1);
    c1 = Y3 - (m1 * X2);
    c2 = Y4 - (m2 * X2);
    // CASE m1==m2 should be handled.
    p.x = (c2 - c1) / (m1 - m2);
    p.y = (m2 * p.x) + c2;
    } else { 
    p.x = X1;
    p.y = Y1;
    }
    #not able to also understand calculation 
    if (verbosityValue >= 1)
      loginfo<<"found crossing point @ " << p.x << " " << p.y << endl;
    return p;
}

Output:
first
found crossing point @ 7.84541e-08 -1.96135e-09 with type 0
found crossing point @ 0.528564 0.0182859        with type 1  

second
found crossing point @ 0.654357 -0.0163589  with type 0
found crossing point @ 1.25827 4.31937e-05  with type 1
```

Comment: Give a link to your image and someone will edit (maybe even me) :P. Moreover, you need to improve your question, it's unclear.

Comment: Real code would also be nice. This isn't C++ code; `#` is not a comment character in C++

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a straightforward implementation. For a given point `x,y` on the curve, find the slope, draw a line through the slope, find where that line would cross the x axis, and then find the new y value at that point. For well-behaved functions, the new y value is a lot closer to 0 than the initial y value. You iterate until the approximation is good enough.

If you look at the graph, you see that the middle part is quite straight. Hence, the slope of the line is a locally good approximation of the curve, and your new y value is a lot closer to zero (At least 10x times, probably 100x, looking at the graph.0. If you start on the the steeper slopes on either side, you'll need one extra step. Your second x point will be on the middle part.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I have one question when we have type 1 than we get appropriate value but if type=0 than we get entire different value. Not able to understand c value with type 0 and 1

Comment: With type=0, c is derived from vcc; with type = 1 c is derived from vcc.